# Load CKEditor (WYSIWYG) on click in Drupal

Tags: drupal, onclick, wysiwyg

I installed the `CKEditor`-module but it a rather large page with a lot of WYSIWYG-editors. So it takes a while when the page is loaded on slow computers.
Is there a way to load the WYSIWYG-editor when the user clicks inside the edit-text-area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `wysiwyg` module. there are some settings that let's you click on a button to load the Editor

Comment: I looked into the settings, but didn't found anything. Do you happen to know which setting to adjust?

Comment: in Drupal 6, go to "admin/settings/wysiwyg", then edit your default profile. In "Basic setup" you'll have to uncheck the "Enabled by default" option

Comment: The `Enabled by default` option is also there on D7, but it disables the editor completely and won't show him automatically...

Comment: yeah, the editor is disabled but under the textarea is a link that makes your editor load when you click on it